# Getting unknown property: yii\db\Connection::enableLogging

Tags: yii2, composer

Странная ошибка, появилась после того как я в системных фалах yii2 вставлял var_dump. после того как убрал его и сохранил все появилась она. И еще
http://joxi.ru/Vm6BWwoiDVq6Mm
Кто нибудь сталкивался с таким при composer update? Что делать? При генерации токена пишет что токен не валиден.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо сгенерировать токен на гитхабе (ссылка в консоле) и указать его. Такая ситуация возникает, потому что композер делает много запросов на сервера гитхаба и гитхаб просит подтвердить свои намерения.